# Get/Set the value in the cache using the AtomicReference in java

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, synchronized

I've already posted this question on codereview site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158999/get-set-the-value-in-the-cache-using-the-atomicreference-in-java , but thought of posting here, so that it reaches the wider audience and i can get the quicker solution posting it here as well.

I am having below code which get and set the data in the cache using the synchronized block and i want to know if i can optimize the below code :-

```
 public int getValue() {
    AtomicReferenceTest<Integer> cachedIntRef = new AtomicReference<Integer>();
    boolean wasCached = true;
    Integer cachedInt = cachedIntRef.get();
    if (cachedInt == null) {
        synchronized (cachedIntRef) {
            cachedInt = cachedIntRef.get();
            if (cachedInt == null) {
                wasCached = false;
                // Make DB call to get the data and update the cache.
                cachedInt = baseDao.getCloudMaximumWeight();
                cachedIntRef.set(cachedInt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know if is there is any way by which i can remove the **synchronized** block and optimize further or this code is already optimized?

EDIT :- i'll remove the question from one of the site, if i get the answer on any of the site. Also when i profile my application sometime even with less no of threads, i see threads blocking on `synchronized` piece of code. which made me think as i code is using the `AtomicRef` , somehow i can get rid of `syncronized` or is there is some other better way of optimize the code.

Comment: This looks like a code review question allright, I don't think duplicating it on SO is such a good idea.

Comment: @Mena , yeah i posted there, but didn't get any response, so thought of posting here. will remove it once i get an answer

Comment: What makes you think that the code needs to be optimized?

Comment: @Gray updated it in question

Comment: Why does it need to be synchronized at all?  Worst case, the DB would be hit a couple extra times.  That's probably still overall faster than synchronizing every invocation.  What does a profiler say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if is there is any way by which i can remove the synchronized block and optimize further or this code is already optimized?

I assume that optimizing the code means removing the `synchronized` block.  The problem with that thinking is that most likely your `dao` call is *significantly* more expensive than `synchronized`.  Any IO (especially to a remote database) is going to be at least 4+ orders of magnitude more expensive than the locking.

That said, you can remove the `synchronized` block if you don't mind multiple DAO calls when initializing the cache.   If the DAO calls are inexpensive then having 2 threads making them maybe isn't a problem.  There is a race condition on which one's answer will be put into the cache but chances are their results will be the same anyway.  I often do this and assume that as the application starts up, the first couple of calls are going to be more expensive as the cache warms.  But are 2 threads making the same DAO request *ever* going to be faster than 1 thread doing it and 1 waiting for the other thread to finish?

If there is a number of *different* DAO calls then you can try some sort of lock segregation so not all cache requests go through the same lock.  This would allow some parallelization which might help.  I can't tell if your code is specific or an example of the problem.  This is how the `ConcurrentHashMap` works for example.

But really I would be sure that this section of code has performance problems before I worry too much about it.  And even if a profiler is saying that it is a primary time sink, it may just be that the DAO calls are the most expensive part of the equation so saving a couple with `synchronization` would be the best way to speed it up anyway.  You can take out the dao calls and replace with a straight assignment if you need to see if it the `synchronized` or `dao.*` calls that is the problem.

Comment: thanks for the answer, there is just 1 costly dao call and this cache is regularly updates within the lifecycle of application. i was having another scenario where i used concurrent-hashmap, computeifAbsent method and get rid of synchronized method

Comment: But in this case, my concern is can i achieve , some kind of functionality like `computeIfAbsent` has, where i can pass `method ref` in which it makes the DB calls, but only when cache is empty and get rid of synchronized block as well.

Comment: Under the covers CHM has very similar locking (albeit not using `synchronized`).  It uses segmented locking to provide parallelization and per-instance locking to control the per-entry race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using volatile integer instead. Maybe I am missing something here but I don't see the use case for the AtomicReference here.

Comment: `AtomicReference` is necessary if you want the value to be null-able.